# Custom directive under ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new bie in angular js, I am  trying to implement a overflow menu provided by carbon components i.e https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components/tree/master/src/components.

If I dont put mycustom directive under ng-repeat, it is working fine. But if i put it under ng-repeat it is failing. 
When i try to consume it in html, overflow menu is not 
displaying.  Please suggest what i am missing here.

Comment: Can you post your code please? Pastebin/jsfiddle etc., it would help people see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Carbon components in dynamically created DOM elements (e.g. overflow menu in your case) need manual instantiation/release. Manual instantiation can be done by e.g. `const instance = CarbonComponents.OverflowMenu.create(theElementOfOverflowMenu)` and release can be done by `overflowMenuInstance.release()`. Given you have a directive with an overflow menu in it - Your directive should have the `.create()` call in `link()` and the `.release()` call in `$destroy` event listener. Here is an example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyAppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myArray = [{}, {}, {}];
  })
  .directive('myOverflowMenu', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: [
        '<div data-overflow-menu tabindex="0" aria-label="Overflow menu description" class="bx--overflow-menu">',
        '<svg class="bx--overflow-menu__icon" width="4" height="20" viewBox="0 0 4 20" fill-rule="evenodd">',
        '<circle cx="2" cy="2" r="2"></circle>',
        '<circle cx="2" cy="10" r="2"></circle>',
        '<circle cx="2" cy="18" r="2"></circle>',
        '</svg>',
        '<ul class="bx--overflow-menu-options">',
        '<li class="bx--overflow-menu-options__option">',
        '<button class="bx--overflow-menu-options__btn">Stop app</button>',
        '</li>',
        '<li class="bx--overflow-menu-options__option">',
        '<button class="bx--overflow-menu-options__btn">Restart app</button>',
        '</li>',
        '</ul>',
        '</div>'
      ].join(''),
      link: function (scope, element) {
        const overflowMenu = CarbonComponents.OverflowMenu.create(element[0].querySelector('[data-overflow-menu]'));
        scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
          overflowMenu.release();
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/carbon-components@7.4.4/css/carbon-components.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/carbon-components@7.12.1/scripts/carbon-components.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyAppController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in myArray">
    <my-overflow-menu></my-overflow-menu>
  </div>
</div>
```